# Changing a Details of Symbolic Link

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, add-type

Can't figure out whats the issue with `CreateFilePrivate` .

- called from PowerShell, with:

  ```
  $path = "D:\temporal\t1.txt"
  $item = Get-Item -LiteralPath $path -Force
  [Win32]::setFileDetails($path, $item.CreationTimeUtc.ToFileTime(), $item.LastAccessTimeUtc.ToFileTime(), $item.LastWriteTimeUtc.AddDays(1).ToFileTime())
  ```

```
using System;       // required for some of it's content .
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;       // DllImport, Marshal
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;      // SafeFileHandle
using System.IO;        // FileShare, FileMode

public class Win32 {

    struct FILE_BASIC_INFO {
        internal long CreationTime;
        internal long LastAccessTime;
        internal long LastWriteTime;
        internal long ChangeTime;
        internal uint FileAttributes;       // binary
    };

    [Flags]
    enum AccessRights: uint {       // System.Messaging.GenericAccessRights doesn't work in Windows Powershell 's `Add-Type` .
        // # GenericAccessRights
        Read = 0x80000000,      // 2147483648 "-2147483648"
        Write = 0x40000000,     // 1073741824
        Execute = 0x20000000,   // 536870912
        All = 0x10000000,       // 268435456
        None = 0x00000000       // 0
    };

    [Flags]
    enum CreateFile_Options: uint {
        // # Flags
        ReparsePoint = 0x00200000,      // do not follow if a symbolic link . "OPEN_REPARSE_POINT"
        BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 0x02000000,
        DELETE_ON_CLOSE = 0x04000000,
        NO_BUFFERING = 0x20000000,
        OPEN_NO_RECALL = 0x00100000,
        OVERLAPPED = 0x40000000,
        POSIX_SEMANTICS = 0x01000000,
        RANDOM_ACCESS = 0x10000000,
        SESSION_AWARE = 0x00800000,
        SEQUENTIAL_SCAN = 0x08000000,
        WRITE_THROUGH = 0x80000000
    };

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SetFileInformationByHandle(
        SafeFileHandle item,
        int Type_v,     // `enum FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS`
        ref FILE_BASIC_INFO sho_v,      // "Pointer"
        uint size_v
    );
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandleEx(
        SafeFileHandle item,
        int Type_v,     // `enum FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS`
        ref FILE_BASIC_INFO sho_v,      // "Pointer"
        uint size_v
    );
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileW", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFilePrivate(
        string path,
        AccessRights v_Access,
        FileShare v_Share,
        IntPtr v_Security,      // `null` for default . `ref (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES {})`
        FileMode a,
        CreateFile_Options v_Options,
        IntPtr Template     // `(SafeFileHandle) null` : "SafeHandle cannot be null" .
    );
    
    public static void setFileDetails (
        string path,
        long CreationEventTime,
        long ReadingEventTime,
        long WritingEventTime
        // System.IO.FileAttributes FileAttributes
    ) {
        SafeFileHandle item = CreateFilePrivate(path , AccessRights.Read | AccessRights.Write , FileShare.Read , IntPtr.Zero , FileMode.Open , CreateFile_Options.ReparsePoint , IntPtr.Zero);

        Console.WriteLine(path)     // the output path 100% targets a Symbolic Link
        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());     // "2"/"ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"
        
        var BasicInfo = new FILE_BASIC_INFO() {};
        GetFileInformationByHandleEx(item, (int) 0, ref BasicInfo, (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(BasicInfo));
        
        BasicInfo = new FILE_BASIC_INFO() {
            CreationTime = CreationEventTime,
            LastAccessTime = ReadingEventTime,
            LastWriteTime = WritingEventTime,
            ChangeTime = BasicInfo.ChangeTime,
            FileAttributes = (uint) 0       // `(uint) 0` to not change any
        };
        SetFileInformationByHandle(item, (int) 0, ref BasicInfo, (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(BasicInfo));
    }
}
```

edited with fixes for issues pointed out by @Dai .

Comment: You should add some error checking to all API calls.

Comment: DllImport stuff doesn't output errors from calling them ? would this work `DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true <<_>> Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());` ? it outputs "998": "ERROR_NOACCESS / Invalid access to memory location." after `CreateFilePrivate(` .

Comment: @SimonMourier seems working, because it outputs "6": "ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE"; after the `<<_>>FileInformationByHandle` calls . but i still don't understand whats the issue with CreateFilePrivate .

Comment: if i try to use `CreateFileW` directly, result is the same .

Comment: You're missing SetLastError on DllImport declarations (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror#examples)  for API that document calling GetLastError on error. Then you can call Marshal.GetLastError https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error

Comment: thats what i just said that did .

Comment: `struct_null ` <-- This is _not_ how you use `lpSecurityAttributes`

Comment: @Dai i don't see a reason for it to not work (and definitely it shouldn't result into "ERROR_NOACCESS") . lpSecurityAttributes will take 150 lines to add, and is completely not needed .

Comment: Why have you commented-out the 7th parameter of `CreateFileW` (`hTemplateFile`)? An "optional" parameter in Win32 is not the same thing as a JS-style nor C#-style optional parameter - the docs say you should pass `NULL` if you're not specifying `hTemplateFile`.

Comment: there is error i get, commented next to it .

Comment: Because `ref struct_null` is **not** a null-pointer. .NET's marshaller will give Win32 a valid pointer address to an invalid-sized struct in-memory.

Comment: `NULL` (a C macro) is not `null` in C#.

Comment: well, yea . maybe you know how to make a null pointer working and avoid `ref <<identified expected>> v_Security` error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dllimport by default converts parameters passed to the Method, to some specific encoding, so for Unicode `<<name>>W` Win32 commands it requires it's CharSet being set .

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
```

IntPtr works as Pointer, so when:

- Pointer to null is required .
- and the needed Type doesn't support null .

IntPtr Type and IntPtr.Zero can be used .

thanks to everyone who tried to help, especially @SimonMourier @Dai .